# Angular 2 Select Label placeholder is being overwritten

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to stackoverflow and I have a small issue.

I have been trying to set a placeholder for a drop down select in Angular 2 with bootstrap.

This is my Html

```
<div class="organization-field col-sm-8" >
    <div style="display: inline-block; width:100%;">
        <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2"  [formControl]="organizationName" type="string" name="organizationName" (change)="logIn()"  >
            <option [selected]="true" disabled>Select Organization ...</option>
            <option *ngFor="let name of organizationNames" [value]="name.$organizationId"  required>
                {{name.$organizationName}}
            </option>
        </select> 
    </div>
```

The placeholder works however my ngFor is actually generated by doing a call to my backend which is Firebase.

This is TS file

```
this.organizationService.getOrgs().subscribe(data => {
    data.forEach(org => {
        var newOrg = this.organizationService.convertOrg(org); 
        this.organizationNames.push(newOrg)
    });
})
```

The problem occurs once i have actually retrieve the data from the database, the placeholder disappears making the placeholder looking really ugly. Any help will be extremely helpful

Comment: Can you try by adding `value=""` in first option?

Comment: What about something like `<option *ngFor="let x of this.organizationService.getOrgs().startWith({$organizationName: 'Select Organization ...' }) | async; let i = index" [disabled]="i === 0">`  just a thought...

Answer (score 0):

Just a little bit of mods on the code

```
<div class="organization-field col-sm-8">
<div style="display: inline-block; width:100%;">
    <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" formControl="organizationName" type="string" name="organizationName" (change)="logIn()">
        <option  value="" disabled>Select Organization ...</option>
        <option *ngFor="let name of organizationNames" [value]="name.$organizationId" required>{{name.$organizationName}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The trick is after you update the controller with your data. the selected is useless or not recommendable on reactive forms and selects.

```
this.organizationService.getOrgs().subscribe(data => {
data.forEach(org => {
    var newOrg = this.organizationService.convertOrg(org);
    this.organizationNames.push(newOrg)
});
this.form.controls.organizationName.setValue("",{ emitEvent: false} );
```

})

I have no idea whats the name of the FormGroup, I just put form as a demo.

Let me know how did you go.

Cheers!